# Dynamic drop down box change depend on database in CakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP, the problem is I need to create the dynamic values to drop down box the values which are come from mysql.the following is code which i used in controller:

```
$wires = $this->wire->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('wire_id'=>$wire_id)));
foreach($wires as $key=>$gs) {
    $options[$gs['wires']['type_of_wire']] = $gs['wires']['type_of_wire'];
    $options1[$gs['wires']['length']] = $gs['wires']['length'];
    $options2[$gs['wires']['color']] = $gs['wires']['color'];
}
```

In ctp

```
echo $this->Form->input('wire', array('type' => 'select', 'class'=>'dropdn', 'options'=> $options, 'selected'=> $options, 'div'=>false, 'label'=>false,'id'=>'metal'));
echo $this->Form->input('wire', array('type' => 'select', 'class'=>'dropdns', 'options'=> $options1, 'selected'=> $options, 'div'=>false, 'label'=>false,'id'=>'metal'));
echo $this->Form->input('wire', array('type' => 'select', 'class'=>'dropdned', 'options'=> $options1, 'selected'=> $options, 'div'=>false, 'label'=>false,'id'=>'metal'));
```

Here I create three drop down boxes, but the problem is if I changed the drop down box value type of wire means its dynamically change its correct length and color for rest of the drop down box.

I also tried it ob onchange but I can't.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Cakephp. Jquery is best for this.

Comment: @Moshe Katz,yes i did with it jquery functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AJAX calling for dynamic drop down list. something like this in your layout/ where you have jquery defined..

```
$('#metal').change(function() {
var wire= $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "HERE GIVE URL TO YOUR ACTION WHERE YOU FETCH DATA FROM TABLE",
    data: { wire: wire , submit: "submit" },
    success: function(result){
                $("#metal").html(result);
            }
    });
  });
})
```

Then  in your controller, action for ajax call--

```
public function get_wires()
{
    $this->autoRender=false; 
    $value=$_POST['wire'];
    $wire_length = $this->wire->find('list',array('fields' => array('wire_length'),'conditions' => array('wire'=>$value)));
    foreach($wire_length as $q)
    {                                                       
        $data[]="<option>".$q."</option>";              
    }
    print_r($data);
}
```

Then post this value you get into your form in view.ctp page.